# Variables to appear in TextView

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately, none of my Strings will appear in a `TextView` that I have created. I'm looking to have two TextViews; one for `cost` and the other for `time`.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int intTime = 30;
int intCost = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CheckBox CP = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkPepperoni);
    CheckBox CS = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkSausage);
    CheckBox CB = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBacon);
    CheckBox CM = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkMushroom);

    final ImageView cheese =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCheese);
    final ImageView pepperoni =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPepperoni);
    final ImageView sausage =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSausage);
    final ImageView bacon =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBacon);
    final ImageView mushroom =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMushroom);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



    CP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                        //Pepperoni Listener
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  if(isChecked1){                       

                      pepperoni.setImageResource(R.drawable.pepperoni);
                      intTime = intTime + 6;
                      intCost = intCost + 5;
                    }
                   else{

                        pepperoni.setImageResource(0);
                        intTime = intTime - 6;
                        intCost = intCost - 5;
                   }

    }});

    CS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    //Sausage Listener
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  if(isChecked2){                       

                      sausage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sausage);
                      intTime = intTime + 6;
                      intCost = intCost + 5;

                    }
                   else{

                       sausage.setImageResource(0);
                       intTime = intTime - 6;
                        intCost = intCost - 5;

                   }

    }});

    CB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  if(isChecked3){                       

                      bacon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bacon);
                      intTime = intTime + 6;
                      intCost = intCost + 5;

                    }
                   else{

                       bacon.setImageResource(0);
                       intTime = intTime - 6;
                        intCost = intCost - 5;

                   }

    }});

    CM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  if(isChecked4){                       

                      mushroom.setImageResource(R.drawable.mushroom);
                      intTime = intTime + 6;
                      intCost = intCost + 5;

                    }
                   else{

                       mushroom.setImageResource(0);
                       intTime = intTime - 6;
                        intCost = intCost - 5;

                   }

    }});


    ImageButton IB = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnGo);
    IB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String time = Integer.toString(intTime);
            String cost = Integer.toString(intCost);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("keyTime", time);
            editor.putString("keyCost", cost);

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class));

        }

    });
    }

}
```

ResultActivity.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    TextView cost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCost);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String strTime = sharedPref.getString("keyTime", "");
    String strCost = sharedPref.getString("keyTime", "");

    cost.setText("cost" + (strCost));
    time.setText("and " + strTime + " to deliver.");
    }

}
```

Anybody have any advise? I just need to have strCost and strTime show up in the `TextView` in ResultActivity.java.

Comment: It's the same code as in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176123/the-final-local-variable-cannot-be-assigned-since-it-is-defined-in-an-enclosing/30176252#30176252 , but with solution proposed soultion, why people need to help you, if you even can't say thx ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do a commit when working with the editor:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("keyTime", time);
editor.putString("keyCost", cost);
editior.commit();
```

Comment: Also look at your shared preferences keys when you get the shared preferences. They both have keys "keyTime".